# Error While testing chained payment on ios

Tags: ios, paypal, chained, chained-payments

I am an iphone developer, first time trying to implement pay-pal transections in my project.
I have implemented simple project to perform chained payments with paypal sdk, but it gives me an error that "payment declined. The recipient cannot receive payments." Please help me to solve this issue.
thanks in advance

Comment: have you registered at paypal developer https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/index and recipient is "facilitator" account i.e Business account and transfering from personal account.

Comment: yes,I have tested it for parallel payments,parallel payments are working fine,but I did few changes for chained payment in project,its giving me this error.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, its working now I think problem was in recipients accounts that I were using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Paypal Integration, test your functionality in Sandbox mode and you need to register at  [paypal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/index) and recipient is "facilitator" account i.e Business account and transferring from personal account.